# Dynamic Dropdown with Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

We have setup 2 Dropdown Lists. Once a user selects an option drop dropdown 1 and and option from dropdown 2, once selected and they click the submit button, we need it to take the a page.

Currently the code is setup as a popup and displays the URL name which is not what we want.

Hope to hear from someone soon with a solution.

Thanks,
Marcelo

```js
<script>
function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
 
selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
 
}
if (chosen == "1") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('UV Protection','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Acne','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Dry Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Eczema','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Itchy Relief','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Redness','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Sensitive Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/');
}
if (chosen == "2") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('UV Protection','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Acne','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Dry Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Eczema','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Itchy Relief','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Redness','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Sensitive Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/');
}
if (chosen == "3") {
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('UV Protection','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Acne','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Dry Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Eczema','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Itchy Relief','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Redness','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
  selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = 
new Option('Sensitive Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/');
}
}
</script>
```

```html
<form name="myform"><div class="centre">
<select name="optone" size="1"
onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[ document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value=" " selected="selected">I am</option>
<option value="1">Someone who works with my hands</option>
<option value="2">Someone who works with my feet</option>
<option value="3">Someone who works with my body</option>
</select><br /> <br />

<select name="opttwo" size="1">
<option value=" " selected="selected">and I need</option>
</select>

<input type="button" name="go" value="Value Selected"
onclick="alert(document.myform.opttwo.options[ document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value);">
</div></form>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In the future, make sure to phrase your questions as **questions**. Your post didn't ask a question, but I gave an answer to what I **think** you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onclick="alert(...)"`, try `onclick="window.location(...)"` to send the browser to that page.

**Update Re: our conversation**

To make it cleaner, I would put all of your options into a big <strike>array</strike> object that you can do various (easier) functions on:

```
  var options = {
    "hands" : [
      ['UV Protection','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
      ['Acne','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
      ['Dry Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
      ['Eczema','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
      ['Itchy Relief','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
      ['Redness','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
      ['Sensitive Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/'],
    ],
    "feet" : [
      ['UV Protection','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
      ['Acne','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
      ['Dry Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
      ['Eczema','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
      ['Itchy Relief','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
      ['Redness','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
      ['Sensitive Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/'],
    ],
    "body" : [
      ['UV Protection','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
      ['Acne','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
      ['Dry Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
      ['Eczema','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
      ['Itchy Relief','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
      ['Redness','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
      ['Sensitive Skin','http://example.com/portfolio-item/body-lotion/'],
    ]
  };
```

Comment: Hello Philtune,

I changed the code as you mentioned but now when I click on "Value Selected" button, it doesn't do anything.

<input type="button" name="go" value="Value Selected"
onclick="window.location(document.myform.opttwo.options[ document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value);">
</div></form>

URL that i'm testing is http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/test.php

Comment: Hmm, your code seems a bit complex to me... I might go a different route altogether.

Comment: What would you do... what would you recommend?

Comment: Well, I started writing up some code, but I just don't have the time right now. Basically, I would take out the `onchange` and `onclick` properties in your html and put them in your Javascript. Then you can more easily watch your client console for any errors and specific line numbers to help you track down the issue. I'd also put all of your options into a 3-dimensional array. I will post that part in my answer here in a second.

Comment: Thanks @philtune. Actually is there a full example that you can provide that I can copy and paste into my test.php file... that would be great. Thanks again for helping out.